# Firebird - monitoramento de transação

Tags: sql, firebird

Atualizei meu `Firebird` para a `versão 2.5` e gostaria de visualizar as transações, vi em vários links que o comando:
`SELECT * FROM mon$statements` resolve, mas esse comando me da um erro:

> *Undefined name. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -204. Table unknown. MON$STATEMENTS. unknown ISC error 336397208*

Pelo que entedi ele não acha essa tabela, também puderá, pois a minha conexão que faço é diretamente dentro de uma database que não tem essa "tabela" mon$statements, então como proceder ?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o código abaixo vai trazer como resposta todas as transações inicializadas. Assim poderá identificar a que está te causando problemas.

```
SELECT    
    mon$transaction_id,
    mon$attachment_id,
    mon$state,
    mon$timestamp,
    mon$top_transaction,
    mon$oldest_transaction,
    mon$oldest_active,
    mon$isolation_mode,
    mon$lock_timeout,
    mon$read_only,
    mon$auto_commit,
    mon$auto_undo,
    mon$stat_id,
    case mon$isolation_mode
       when 0 then 'Consistency'
       when 1 then 'Concurrency'
       when 2 then 'Read Committed Record Version'
       when 3 then 'Read Committed'
       else 'Unknown'
    end as Desc_Isolation,
    case MON$LOCK_TIMEOUT
       when -1 then 'Infinite Wait'
       when  0 then 'No wait'
       else 'Timeout ' || cast(MON$LOCK_TIMEOUT as varchar (20))
    end as Desc_TimeOut
from mon$transactions
order by 1
```

Comment: Bem Vindo ao Site, sugiro que edite sua resposta e adicione mais detalhes!

Comment: Respostas contendo apenas código não são ideais por não explicam como resolver o problema. Tente editar sua resposta para que fique melhor.

Comment: tentei rodar esse código deu esse erro `SQL error code = -204.
Table unknown.
MON$TRANSACTIONS.
`

Answer (score -2):

Você poder verificar o que está acontecendo com os passos abaixo:

**1. Run > Services.msc (Firebird Database Server)**

**2. Se estiver usando ibexpert, tenta reconectar na base novamente.**

**3. Se o erro persistir você tentar reinstalar o firebird.**